# Isolating text using pipelin and awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have blocks of texts that I got using grep and I want to isolate areas with just
`[A-Za-z}+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+` using pipelin and awk
or

`/(any number of letters)/(Any number) /(Any Number)`

Slashes are part of the string that I'm interested in. I'm very new to linux environment and it's giving me trouble.

Comment: I would think that using `grep -o /[A-Za-z]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+` to output only the actual matches (as opposed to `grep`s default of printing the entire line that contains each match) might be better than using `awk` in this case...

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '^/[[:alpha:]]\+/[[:digit:]]\+/[[:digit:]]\+$'
```